# R ggplot2 grouping bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm really new to ggplot2 but trying to learn. I have my data in long form and it looks like this:

```
Year    School Type     Stat                Value
2011    Middle School   Tobacco Use         7.5
2011    Middle School   Cigarettes          4.3
2011    Middle School   Smokeless Tobacco   2.2
2011    Middle School   Hookahs             1
2011    Middle School   E-cigarettes        0.6
2011    High School     Tobacco Use         24.3
2011    High School     Cigarettes          15.8
2011    High School     Smokeless Tobacco   7.3
2011    High School     Hookahs             4.1
2011    High School     E-cigarettes        1.5
```

The full set is here: http://pastebin.com/VUvWhC4x

What I want to do is make two graphs, one for Middle School and one for High School. I can easily subset this into those groups so let's try for Middle School. I'm using a deplry verb here.

```
middle = as.data.frame(filter(data,School.Type=="Middle School"))
```

What I want the graph to look like is each stat will go along the x-axis and then the years will be graphed separately in a row for that year. Then move on to the next stat and the same thing. The years are 2011-2014. It's very much simulating this graph:

[image]

The best I can do is this code:

```
ggplot(middle, aes(factor(Stat), Value, fill = factor(Year)) + 
+geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
+scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

which produces [image]

I would like to group these by stat and then from year 2011-2014 for each stat. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are close - you want `Stat` mapped to the x axis and `Value` to y. Then you fill by `Year` and specify that the  bars should be dodged (i.e. side by side).

This is pretty close to the plot you posted as the desired output.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(middle, aes(x=Stat, y=Value, fill=factor(Year))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position ='dodge', color='black') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!! :)